# Regex to find concatenation caracter between string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following problem, I allow my user to enter code in an editor and I want to replace the concatenation character, here my exemple :

```
1) "tttt"+"zzzz"
2) "+"
3) 'aaaa'+'cccc'
4) "'+'"
5) "az+d"
6) ""+""+""
7) 1+1
```

for the 1,3 and 6 I should replace the '+'

now I've this regex :

```
(["'])(?:(?=(\\?))\2.)*?\1
```

that select exactly what I don't want!

here the link to the online tool I use https://regex101.com/r/rWigkP/1

Comment: Capture what you need to keep, just match what you need to replace - https://regex101.com/r/xecGmZ/1

Comment: If you're really allowing them to enter **code**, a single regular expression is not sufficient to parse it, not even to do the simple thing you've shown above.  (From context I'll infer *JavaScript code* but this is true for nearly anything we refer to as "code.")

Comment: I need just to replace a character for the library I use to compute the code however Wiktor the problem with your method is that I have also string

Comment: `.replace(/(["'])(?:(?=(\\?))\2.)*?\1|([^])/g, function(a,x,y,z) { return z ? " " : a; })`?

Comment: I like the way you do it but it does it for space also I tryed using \w but not succesfully

Comment: figured out = .replace(/(["'])(?:(?=(\\?))\2.)*?\1|([^])/g, (a, x, y, z) => {
      return z === `~` ? `+` : a
    })

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why use regex, you dont need perfomance for a small string of code, it would be more clear just normal code.
Split your string and Just remove '+' if index is even

```
value.split('"').map((v, ind) => 
  v.trim() === '+' && 0 === ind % 2 ? '' : v
).join('"')
```